# I am getting error while making React app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

When I try to make a React app using **npx create-react-app amazon**
It shows me

```
Creating a new React app in E:\React\amazon.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...totype.trimstart":"^1'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\SVG\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-10-16T06_12_32_500Z-debug.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting amazon/ from E:\React
Done.
```

Thanks

Comment: Try cleaning your cache: npm cache clean --force

Comment: Tried that did not work @vanshaj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it got fixed I had to uninstall node.js, delete all folders and re-install node.js and it worked!